# Setting a default value for missing fields during indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to create an elastic search mapping where during indexing of data if a field is missing it should add some default value.

PUT my_index

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "status_code": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "response": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PUT my_index/doc/1

```
{ "statuscode": "200" }
```

So, as in the above example response field is missing , is it possible to add some default value during indexing for response.?

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to do this with elasticsearch. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17659) in elasticsearch repository for this feature. For now, you will need to modify the document the way you want before actually sending it to elasticsearch.

Hope that helps.